# Spring: Got error when initializing a database instance using Spring XML

Tags: database, spring, initialization

Here is my XML snippet:

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
<jdbc:script location="/WEB-INF/sqlscripts/age.sql" encoding="UTF-8" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

When starting my Spring web application via Jetty, I got the following error:

```
        Context initialization failed
        org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Failed to execute database script; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement at line 1 of resource ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/sqlscripts/age.sql]: I?N?S?E?R?T? ?A?g?e?G?r?o?u?p? ?(?d?e?f?a?u?l?t?O?p?t?i?o?n?,? ?d?e?s?c?r?i?p?t?i?o?n?,? ?d?i?s?p?l?a?y?S?o?r?t?,? ?n?a?m?e?,? ?c?o?d?e?,? ?l?o?c?a?l?e?)? ?V?A?L?U?E?S? ?(?1?,? ?N?U?L?L?,? ?1?,? ?N?'?1?6?-?2?0?'?,? ?N?'?1?6?-?2?0?'?,? ?N?'?e?n?_?U?S?'?)?
    .....
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'S'.

....
```

I don't know whether these question marks in the error message come from. The SQL statement in the age.sql has one line:

```
INSERT age(defaultOption, description, displaySort, name, code, locale) VALUES (1, NULL, 1, N'16-20', N'16-20', N'en_US');
```

I was able to run the same SQL statement successfully within MS SQL server manually. My SQL statement can have foreign characters.

I am using Spring 3.2.

What went wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The file (example age.sql) having SQL inserts has encoding UTF-8 because it has characters of different languages. I changed it to UTF-8 No BOM. Then it worked.

Hope this helps someone else.